# Intrusion detection in home security suites

Tags: ids

Emsisoft announced that internet security has been removed from their product lineup and they stick with Windows firewall and "fortify" that ("blocks illegitimate manipulations of Windows Firewall rules").

Are there any needs for host and network based intrusion detection and prevention in home security suites?
( Eset & Kaspersky continue to deliver IDS & IPS in home lineup )

Comment: Are you asking in general about the need for HIDS/NIDS in home use? I'm not clear why you talk about Emsisoft.

Comment: It's just an example. as you mention,"need for HIDS/NIDS in home use"?

Comment: You are missing the point; those are different things where one can not replace the other. Yet, there isn't much to exfiltrate in home use and an IDS won't help with ransomware. So… well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use laptops, tablets, mobile phones over wifi at home and elsewhere, then  host based solutions are critical.  In the age of cloud, there really is no persistent perimeter to protect anymore.

Now whether you need a full fledged IDS/IPS or just a good firewall depends on multiple risk factors including how tasty of a target you may be and what you are doing on your network...so it is debatable and no single answer.

Answer (score 0):

i'm the Emsisoft Community Manager.

To answer your question: "are there any needs for host and network based intrusion detection and prevention in home security suites? ( Eset & Kaspersky continue to deliver IDS & IPS in home lineup )"

On a home user environment, there is absolutely no need of an IDS/IPS ; those features are mostly corporate ones when network attacks are real threats to the company.

Home users face a different kind of threat, which are mostly ransomware and various trojans/keyloggers (those loggers's connections in most cases can be blocked by any classic firewalls.)

**[Emsisoft Anti-Malware](https://www.emsisoft.com/en/software/antimalware/)** will suffice and alert you in case of suspicious outbound connections :)

i hope my answer will satisfy you.